# selection of variables for best fitted model using GAM in R?

Tags: r, variables, selection, gam, mgcv

and I'm trying to use the mgcv to model the relationship between fish abundance and 11 environmental factors as 11 explanatory variables.

y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + ... + s(x11)

I tried with too many models (from 1 variable; 2 variables .... 11 variables models), then using AIC to choose the best fitted model. However, I could not run all the models at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good way of doing inference, though might be OK if you are only interested in doing prediction.

Instead, consider adding `select = TRUE` to the model (it's an argument to `gam()` etc. This argument adds an extra penalty to the null space of the basis (the perfectly smooth parts), which allows you to do model selection as the linear term(s) in each smooth are also shrunk towards zero (a bit like the lasso) and thus can also be selected out of the model.